# Can't seem to resize the working window in TeXnicCenter...?

Tags: windows, texniccenter, resize

All of a sudden, the working window or whatever you want to call it (where you write stuff in LaTex) was more than maximized! It just continues below where my screen ends! :(

This is in TeXnicCenter on Windows 10.

Before it was finite and I could drag and resize. :) Please tell me how to get that situation back. I've tried googling… Thanks for help! Here is a screen shot of current situation. [image]

"Solution-screenshot" below

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Which is your editor? Under which OS?

Comment: TeXnicCenter, if that helps. Don't know what OS is? Using Windows 10. :)

Comment: The Operating System is Windows 10, then. Did you close and reopen your editor (saving first, of course!)

Comment: thx for reply. yes. even restarted computer.

Comment: Does anyone know the official name of the "working area" where I write stuff in LaTex? (Could perhaps make google results better.)

Comment: I don't  know well TeXnic Center, but I know it has  a users' Webpage. Maybe you should ask them if no one can help you here. For me,  the working area should be the *edit window* but this is not necessarily the official name.

Comment: the question is _only_ about texniccenter (you should edit the title) you are asking about that editor, latex isn't involved at all other than that is what you are typing in the editor whose window you want to resize.

Comment: That was very helpful lolz..

Comment: @user205212, the commen5 by David Carlisle *was* in fact quite helpful, so I'm not sure what the "lolz" is supposed to mean.  He's trying to help you write better questions, which will in turn get better answers for you.  I've edited the question to reflect the actual problem.

Comment: Thank you very much to you too... Good man.. ;)

Anyway, finally found solution, which I'll try to explain for others with same issue: right-click Build-output-thingy, think it had to be "docked". When clicking on it and saw as in screenshot, then drag mouse cursor to down arrow (if you want build-thingy docked down there as usual). :)

Comment: Yay, back in business. Cheerio!

Comment: @user205212 please post the answer as an answer (and accept it) don't just leave it as a comment, that clears it from the list of unanswered questions and makes it easier for other people to find the answer

Comment: okidoki, will try

Comment: thanks (voted:-)

Answer (score 1):

Finally found solution, which I'll try to explain for others with same issue: right-click Build-output-thingy, think it had to be "docked"... Anyway, when clicking on it and saw as in screenshot, drag mouse cursor to down arrow (if you want build-thingy docked down there as usual). :)[image]